# Непонятные проблемы с apache

Tags: apache, centos7, virtual-hosts

Вообщем проблема такая, я создал 2 домена и 1 поддомен вот конфиг:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName www.brain-dev.space
ServerAlias beta.brain-dev.space
ServerAdmin support@brain-dev.space
DocumentRoot "/var/www/brain-dev.space" 
<Directory /var/www/brain-dev.space/> 
  AllowOverride All 
  Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName www.license.brain-dev.space 
ServerAlias license.brain-dev.space 
DocumentRoot "/var/www/license.brain-dev.space" 
<Directory /var/www/license.brain-dev.space/> 
  AllowOverride All 
  Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName www.brain-dev.store
ServerAlias brain-dev.store
DocumentRoot "/var/www/brain-dev.store" 
<Directory /var/www/brain-dev.store/> 
  AllowOverride All 
  Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

Теперь если я перехожу на любой адрес то все нормально работает, но если к примеру сделать ошибку например ввести адрес [http://а.brain-dev.store/](http://%D0%B0.brain-dev.store/) то я попадаю на brain-dev.space. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Дайте вопросу нормальное название, отражающее суть проблемы, плиз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache первый блок, если не найдено ни одного другого соответствующего блока, поэтому нужно добавить в верхней части блок без сервера:

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /defaultdir/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName www.brain-dev.space
ServerAlias beta.brain-dev.space
ServerAdmin support@brain-dev.space
DocumentRoot "/var/www/brain-dev.space" 
<Directory /var/www/brain-dev.space/> 
  AllowOverride All 
  Allow from all 
</Directory> 

<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName www.license.brain-dev.space 
ServerAlias license.brain-dev.space 
DocumentRoot "/var/www/license.brain-dev.space" 
<Directory /var/www/license.brain-dev.space/> 
  AllowOverride All 
  Allow from all 
</Directory> 

<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName www.brain-dev.store
ServerAlias brain-dev.store
DocumentRoot "/var/www/brain-dev.store" 
<Directory /var/www/brain-dev.store/> 
  AllowOverride All 
  Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427379/apache-default-virtualhost)